Automate adding members to Azure Active Directory Group from Databricks
I have an azure group which is used to provide viewer access to the powerBI reporting.
The project is in such a way that the users that required permission to view this PowerBI will be changing on every week. Which means we have to clean and update the azure group every week.
I am having list of users with their emailID in a csv file which is updated on weekly basis.
I tried the below script from databricks.
mport requests

# Azure AD group details
dbutils.secrets.list(scope="credentials")
tenant_id = <tenanat_id>
client_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope>",key="<id>")
client_secret = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope>",key="<psswrd>")
group_id = <grp_id>

# List of user object IDs to add to the group
# user_object_ids = ["user1_object_id", "user2_object_id", "user3_object_id"]
user_object_ids = ["user@tpdir.net"]

# Get an access token using client credentials
token_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token"
token_data = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com"
}
token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data)
access_token = token_response.json().get("access_token")

# Add members to the group
graph_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0"
add_member_url = f"{graph_url}/groups/{group_id}/members/$ref"
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
for user_object_id in user_object_ids:
    member_data = {
        "@odata.id": f"{graph_url}/directoryObjects/{user_object_id}"
    }
    response = requests.post(add_member_url, headers=headers, json=member_data)
    if response.status_code == 204:
        print(f"{response.status_code}: User with object ID {user_object_id} added to the group.")
    else:
        print(f"{response.status_code}: Error adding user with object ID {user_object_id}: {response.text} \n")

But I am getting the below error.
400: Error adding user with object ID user@tpdir.net: {"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Invalid object identifier '<pii>user</pii>@tpdir.net'.","innerError":{"date":"2023-05-15T00:00:11","request-id":"<id>","client-request-id":"<id>"}}}

I could try to add members using bulk operations in the portal, but since this is a continuous activity, I have to automate this process.
I tired automating from portal but it is only creating new groups based on the rules which we set.
Is there any way to achieve this ?
Any ways we could automate this process, preferring DevOps pipelines/ADF to execute this. Any leads appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Have a look at the AzureAD Powershell module which might help you here to automate this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0
This script you could even then use to run an Azure Function on a regular schedule. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-powershell
Just coming up with something out of my head:
$Users = Import-Csv "C:\Script\Users.csv"

foreach ($User in $Users) {
  $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$User'" | Select-Object SamAccountName

  Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "group-12354" -Members $adUser.SamAccountName
}

Needs bit more love though :)

The user mentioned here is user email id or objectid ?

It should be the UserPrincipalName - however you could adjust the filter to other attributes
